# Customizing Play/Pause buttons in player framework element WP8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, blend

I am having a small customizing issue on my player framework (XAML WINRT, Windows Phone 8.1 App),  I am trying to remove the circle that are around the Play/Pause and the Full Screen buttons:

[image]

I would like for them to look more like this:

[image]

I have access to the default XAML of the Play/Pause button:

However Blend is not allowing me to create a copy of the element so that I can customize it:

[image]

Do you know what I could do to fix this? Or is there another solution to remove the circle around the play/pause?

**Edit:**

To get the second image I Photoshop the fullscreen button to show what I would like to have.

I have been able to found a work around to find the style "TransportBarButtonStyle" for the AppBarButton that Blend & Visual studio did not want to give it to me.

You can find it on the codeplex site for the player framework: 
https://playerframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Universal.Xaml.Core/Themes/Classic.xaml and you need to look for:

```
<Style x:Key="TransportBarButtonStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton">
```

Comment: How are those buttons designed? Can you show xaml code? Are you using AppBarButton class for this? (It has circle in template) If so, then why not to use normal Button class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at codeplex, https://playerframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Universal.Xaml.Core/Themes/Classic.xaml

I have created a new Style that targets the AppBarButton that doesnt have any circles around its border :

```
<Style x:Key="CircleLessTransportBarButtonStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="IsCompact" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="FullSize"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Compact"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!--<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundEllipse">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!--<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="OutlineEllipse">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundEllipse">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!--<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="OutlineEllipse">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Viewbox Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid Height="40" Width="40">
                            <!--<Ellipse x:Name="BackgroundEllipse" Fill="{ThemeResource AppBarItemBackgroundThemeBrush}" UseLayoutRounding="False"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="OutlineEllipse" Stroke="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="2" UseLayoutRounding="False"/>-->
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" 
                                              Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I hope that this helps you!